# "There's a good film on TV tonight!" "I like watching it!"

Tags: grammar

Essential Grammar in Use, 2nd edition, by Raymond Murphy, contains a "Study guide" -- a test that can show you which grammar topics need revision. I believe that my English is at least slightly above what is studied in the book, and I can easily understand which answer is marked correct in this test. However, I just fail to understand why certain answers are *wrong*.

One of them is this sentence: "There's a good film on TV tonight!", to which one must choose a response:

1. I watch it
2. I like watching it
3. I'm going to watch it

It is very clear why #1 is incorrect, it just makes no sense. #3 is clearly "the" answer. However, I believe that #2 should also be correct. It would mean that I've watched this film many times already, I liked it, and maybe I will watch it today.

I also believe that Raymond Murphy is better at English grammar than I am, so I'd like to know what exactly is wrong with answer number 2.

Comment: #2 also just doesn't make any sense because it's not clear what "it" even refers to.  The first sentence didn't mention what film it was, so how would you know what "it" was or if you liked watching it?

Comment: #2 would be better as "I like watching **that kind of film**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option (2) is unnatural. We don't normally say we *like watching* a film; we would just say that we *like it*. It is understood and obvious that films are watched. The implication would be that we have seen it before and liked it when we did.